# nvd3 Angular2 change chart options dynamically

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-nvd3

i'm using nvd3 for angular2 and i'm trying to change the chart options (yDomain) dynamically after beeing initialized.

```
this.options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'lineChart',
    x: function(d){return d.x;},
    y: function(d){return d.y;},
    yDomain: [1, 2],
```

I've already tried this:

```
this.options.chart.yDomain = [0.1,0.2];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like ng2nvd3 is now https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts (maybe?). Might not be helpful.

Comment: thx for the help. I've tried implementing ngx-charts but I keep getting a "is not a known property" error when I use their HTML-Tags. It seems to be a known issue but I can't get a fix for that either. I'm using Angular 2.4.3 and I literally tried every ngx version. It keeps frustrating me

Comment: I've had that error before. You have to make a change in a json file, but I can't remember the change. Look up that error though.

Comment: zone.js:405 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'view' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-charts-line-chart'.

I keep getting this error. Haven't found the solution you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Honestly that should be correct, I used:

```
$scope.graphOptions.chart.title = ...
```

and at first it didn't work, so I thought that wasn't the correct way to dynamically update the title. I googled, found this thread, later fixed a seemingly unrelated error and it worked properly. Look around your code for other issues `this.options.chart.yDomain` is how you should update it.